# target a specific cell with 2 criteria enter in a userform VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

i am new to VBA and to asking question on forum like that. I have a userform in which i ask a user to fill 2 textbox. The first one is a column (A, B, C, etc..) and the second one is a row (1, 2, 3, etc..). I want the userform to find a specific cell by this 2 criteria and then strikethrough the cell value.

The specific cell is protected before, and should be protected after the strikethrough.

The worksheet his already protected.

I Already have a macro that verify if value as been enter in cells, and protect those who have text, i would like if the strikethrough code don't mess with these other codes.

Thank a lot

If you want me to be more specific just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a cell you can use Range A1 notation like in the follow examples:

```
Range("A1").Select 'Selects Cell A1.

Range(varColumn & varRow).Select 'You can use this changing the variables with your text box values.

ActiveCell.Font.Strikethrough = True 'Once cell is selected you can Strikethrough the Text.

Range(varColumn & varRow).Font.Strikethrough 'Direct Strikethrough
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, it work great. Is it possible to check first if the selected cell is in a specific Range before the strikethrough? Like if the slected cell in textbox1 his not in the range "Week1" then it does nothing, but if it is, then strikethrough.

Comment: Yes, but you need to post another question regarding this last question. Can you please mark my answer as resolve your problem?